# Clustering and grouping noisy time series fuel data

Tags: clustering, data-cleaning

I have a time series of fuel data which are split into distinct clusters (as shown in the image below. I'm looking at the green line). The clusters almost always have a descending gradient. I would like to identify these clusters programmatically (I'm using python). Are there any statistical methods I can use to do this?

Many thanks for any hints.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the plot, I get the impression that the straight, noisyless parts between the clusters are caused by missing data: the last data point of one cluster seems to be connected with the first data point of the next cluster.

If so, you just need to look at adjacent data points. If the temporal distance is above some threshold, then there is a cut between two clusters.

If you wonder how to find a good threshold: collect the temporal distances between adjacent data points. These will consist of a cluster of small values (i.e. all within-cluster-distances) and relatively large outliers (i.e. the between-cluster-distances)

Comment: Yes, the missing data is when the vehicle ignition is off. I'll try the temporal method, thanks.